# Next.js 13 with bazel, swc & rules_ts

Tags: typescript, next.js, bazel

I am trying to migrate my Next.js 13 (appDir) project to bazel. I am using rules_ts & swc. The problem that occurs now is that swc transpiles the files from `ts` to `js`, but next generates various errors instead of working as before. I have included the errors below as code snippets of the output. I followed this [this example](https://github.com/aspect-build/bazel-examples/tree/main/next.js).

This error occurs after transpiling and starting the dev server (just swc). The second problem also occurs when using `tsc` instead of `swc`

Versions:

- next.js - 13.4.12
- bazel - 6.3.1
- rules_js - rules_js-1.31.0
- rules_ts - rules_ts-1.4.5
- rules_swc - rules_swc-1.0.2

```bash
The "use client" directive must be placed before other expressions. Move it to the top of the file to resolve this issue.

    ,-[/tmp/js_run_devserver-4nVW6m/joel-muehlena-website/frontend/blog-v2/src/components/DebugView/DebugView.js:7:1]
  7 |     get: ()=>DebugView
  8 | });
  9 | const _react = require("react");
 10 | 'use client';
    : ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 11 | const DebugView = ({ children  })=>{
 12 |     const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = (0, _react.useState)(false);
 13 |     return React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, isOpen && React.createElement(ViewInternal, {
    `----

Import path:
  ./src/components/DebugView/DebugView.js
  ./src/app/layout.js
```

The following occurs, when fixing the previous error by hand (copying in the transpiled file).

```bash
TypeError: (0 , _google.Roboto) is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/layout.js:51:35)
    at Object.(rsc)/./src/app/layout.js (/tmp/js_run_devserver-acvVOA/joel-muehlena-website/frontend/blog-v2/.next/server/app/not-found.js:8334:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/js_run_devserver-acvVOA/joel-muehlena-website/frontend/blog-v2/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at Function.__webpack_require__.t (/tmp/js_run_devserver-acvVOA/joel-muehlena-website/frontend/blog-v2/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:73:38)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async collectGenerateParams (/home/joel/.cache/bazel/_bazel_joel/8451bc6be2eee7543a3cce2530d3aa56/execroot/joel-muehlena-website/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/node_modules/.aspect_rules_js/next@13.4.12_-1406426654/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:826:17)
    at async Object.loadStaticPaths (/home/joel/.cache/bazel/_bazel_joel/8451bc6be2eee7543a3cce2530d3aa56/execroot/joel-muehlena-website/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/node_modules/.aspect_rules_js/next@13.4.12_-1406426654/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/static-paths-worker.js:87:13) {
  type: 'TypeError'
}
```

Next rule

```
next(
    name = "next",
    srcs = [
        "//frontend/blog-v2/public",
        "//frontend/blog-v2/src/app",
    ],
    data = [
        "next.config.mjs",
        "package.json",
        "postcss.config.js",
        "tailwind.config.js",
        "//:node_modules/@next/mdx",
        "//:node_modules/next",
        "//:node_modules/react",
        "//:node_modules/react-dom",
        "//:node_modules/typescript",
        "//frontend/blog-v2:node_modules/autoprefixer",
        "//frontend/blog-v2:node_modules/rehype-autolink-headings",
        "//frontend/blog-v2:node_modules/rehype-katex",
        "//frontend/blog-v2:node_modules/rehype-slug",
        "//frontend/blog-v2:node_modules/remark-gemoji",
        "//frontend/blog-v2:node_modules/remark-gfm",
        "//frontend/blog-v2:node_modules/remark-math",
        "//frontend/blog-v2:node_modules/tailwindcss",
    ],
    next_bin = "../../node_modules/.bin/next",
    next_js_binary = "//:next_js_binary",
)
```

Example ts rule

```
ts_project(
    name = "app",
    srcs = [
        "layout.tsx",
        "not-found.tsx",
    ],
    allow_js = True,
    assets = [
        "globals.sass",  #keep
        "favicon.ico",  #keep
    ],
    declaration = True,
    declaration_map = True,
    incremental = True,
    preserve_jsx = True,
    resolve_json_module = True,
    transpiler = partial.make(
        swc,
        source_maps = "true",
        swcrc = "//frontend/blog-v2:swcrc",
    ),
    tsconfig = "//frontend/blog-v2:tsconfig",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//:node_modules/rxjs",
        "//frontend/blog-v2:node_modules/next",
        "//frontend/blog-v2/src/components/DebugView",
        "//frontend/blog-v2/src/components/Footer",
        "//frontend/blog-v2/src/logger",
        "//frontend/blog-v2/src/service",
    ],
)
```